# Modifying Depth First Search with dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, depth-first-search

There are a lot of really good DFS python implementations out there, such as [this one](http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/), but none of them include cost. I'd like to be able to record the total cost of a DFS path, but this implementation represents the graph as a dictionary of sets.

```
graph = {'A': set(['B', 'C']),
         'B': set(['A', 'D', 'E']),
         'C': set(['A', 'F']),
         'D': set(['B']),
         'E': set(['B', 'F']),
         'F': set(['C', 'E'])}

def dfs(graph, start):
    visited, stack = set(), [start]
    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            stack.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
    return visited

dfs(graph, 'A') # {'E', 'D', 'F', 'A', 'C', 'B'}
```

I don't think sets could adequately record cost. So I feel that instead representing the graph as a dictionary of dictionaries would be a good way to implement cost. i.e:

```
graph = {'A' : {'C' : 10,
                'D' : 7}
                etc.....
```

My question is, how could this algorithm be modified to use a this new type of graph instead? I'm still very unfamiliar with python syntax, so seeing an example like this really helps.

Alternatively, if there's an even easier way to represent cost, I'm open to suggestions

EDIT: Okay, here's a different way of thinking about it. How can I modify the code above so that it treats the nested dictionaries similarly to sets?

EDIT2: I believe I've solved it myself, now that I understand the keys() function of dictionaries returns a list.

Comment: You'd better move that question to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think that  nested dictionaries as you proposed would be a great idea - take a look at json format, that is maybe what you need. Also DFS doesn't really have to do with cost, so you should probably take a look at other algorithm implementations such as dijkstra etc. that use cost as a significant part of the algorithm.

Comment: I know DFS doesn't use cost, but it can still record it.

Comment: @vishes_shell Are you sure? I thought Code Review was for your own code, not modifying an example you found online. But if that's the better place, I'll gladly move it there.

Comment: @Bob Yes. Code Review is for reviewing your OWN code. We will not review code from code banks or online sites unless you've modified it significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io) is what you are looking for. DFS is included in the package and its graph implementation is what you want. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's interesting, but since I'm still learning python, I thought it would be more useful to see how its done using the default python libraries.

Comment: It is an extremely intuitive structure for creating graphs. Highly recommend.